# how to create multi level ul li in horizontal

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to develop `ul` `li` horizontally where parent will be vertical and child will be align besides them horizontally

code

```
 <ul id="horizontal-list" class="horizontal-list">
   <li>Motors</li>
    <?php
     $query = $this->db->get('countries');
     $countries = $query->result();
     foreach ($countries as $value) { ?>
    <?php if (isset($_GET['country']) && in_array($value->id, @$_GET['country'])) { ?>
    <li class="">
     <span><?= (in_array($value->id, @$_GET['country'])) ? $value->name : null ?>
     <a class="button" id="<?= $value->id ?>" name="country" style="color: white">×</a>
    <?php
      $query = $this->db->get('cities');
      $city = $query->result();
      foreach ($city as $city_value) { ?>
   <?php if (isset($_GET['city']) && in_array($city_value->id, @$_GET['city'])) {
      if ($city_value->country_id == $value->id) {
                                    ?>
     <li class="btn-primary btn-xs">
       <span><?= (in_array($city_value->id, @$_GET['city'])) ? $city_value->name : null ?>
       <a class="button" id="<?= $city_value->id ?>" name="city" style="color: white">×</a>
        </span>
       </li>
   <?php }
     }
  } ?>
          </span>
       </li>
     <br/>
  <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

css

```
<style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        ul.horizontal-list {
            display: flex;
        }

        ul.horizontal-list ul.subhorizontal-list {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    </style>
```

result:

```
country city country city country city
```

what i want

```
country city
country city
country city
```

Comment: You can use `display: flex` to `display: block` or `flex-direction:column;`

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-direction:column...

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.horizontal-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

ul.horizontal-list ul.subhorizontal-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-list">
  <li>country city</li>
  <li>country city</li>
  <li>country city</li>
</ul>  
|
```